# Ruby on Rails - redirect_to after login or logout doesn't do ajax/js/css loads associated with new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm almost done implementing a login system for my Ruby on Rails app. When I log in or log out, I have my session controller redirecting the user to the control panel, or homepage, respectively. However, when redirected to the control panel, the id/class tags on the body, headers, etc. are not replaced, so new HTML specific to the control panel doesn't take effect. When redirected to the homepage on logout, any dynamic content to be loaded on the homepage via AJAX is not loaded as normal. How can I solve this strange problem?

**Here is my Sessions controller:**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user, :only => [:control_panel]
  before_action :not_logged_in, :only => [:create]

  # CREATE SESSION
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      if params[:username_or_email].blank? or params[:login_password].blank?
        # Give feedback for incomplete form
        flash[:feedback] = "Some fields were left empty."
        format.js and return
      end

      if params[:username_or_email].include? '@'
        user = User.find_by_email(params[:username_or_email])
      else
        user = User.find_by_username(params[:username_or_email])
      end

      if user && user.authenticate(params[:login_password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        format.html do
          redirect_to ctrl_path, :notice => "Welcome back, #{user.username}" # Redirect to control panel
        end
      else
        # Give feedback if credentials incorrect
        flash[:feedback] = "The username, email, or password entered was incorrect."
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def control_panel
    # Control panel page
  end

  # DELETE SESSION
  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
As requested here are some of my views...

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= "Ian Hoffman | " + @title || "Railstest" %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <%= favicon_link_tag 'ruby.ico' %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,300italic,700|Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,300" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**control_panel.html.erb**

```
<html id="ctrl-page">

    <head>
        <% @title = "Control Panel" %>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <% if not notice.blank? %>
                <h2 id="ctrl-notice"><%= "#{notice}" %></h2>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

For example: the `<html id="ctrl-page">` is not being inserted upon "redirection," whatever Rails' idea of redirection is. The tag stays as `<html>`, like in the homepage (not shown for reasons).

Comment: Can you also share your view code?

Comment: Could this be the fault of my Application Controller overriding stuff? When I reload the pages, the ajax content/different html appears correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are a few things I see that are a bit odd here... any one of them (or one of them) could be the issue, but I'll comment on what I can see.

1) your template `control_panel` contains the `html` tag - which your templates never should.
the html tag is always done by the layout... the content of the template is inserted into the layout in the part that says `yield` - if you nest an html tag inside an html tag, then the browser often does weird, unexpected things. This is the highest likelihood candidate for fixing your problem

2) technically the `user` variable is out of scope for the controller action here:

```
  if params[:username_or_email].include? '@'
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:username_or_email])
  else
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username_or_email])
  end
```

user is being defined inside the if-section... but not outside of it... if this works at all, I'd be concerned it was only by side-effect.
A more rails-standard practice would be to pull it back into the higher scope eg use:

```
  user = if params[:username_or_email].include? '@'
           User.find_by_email(params[:username_or_email])
         else
           User.find_by_username(params[:username_or_email])
         end
```

3) this is a pet peeve of mine:

```
<%= "#{notice}" %>
```

Notice is already a string... and if it isn't, then the `<%= %>` tags call `to_s` on whatever is inside them anyway. So you don't need to interpolate it inside another sting to make it *more* stringy :)

instead, just use it directly eg:

```
<%= notice %>
```

4) Finally - I'm really hoping you're setting up this login stuff just for fun and to learn about how to do authentication... but aren't going to actually deploy it on a real live system.
No individual programmer is smart enough to outwit the combined wisdom of the known exploits for hacking into Rails... instead professionally, we almost universally use a trusted gem - most people use `devise`.
If you really want to implement your own security system, then you need to read *all* the way through the security guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html
to get a handle on just how hard it is to implement a real secure system... and then once you're done with that realise that this guide is going to be out of date already...

That said - if you're doing it for funsies and learnings, that's totally cool... I've done that too :)
Just replace it with Devise before you go live with anything that actually matters (including your users' personal data).

---

EDIT

your end template should just look something like this:

```
<% @title = "Control Panel" %>
<div id="wrapper">
  <% if not notice.blank? %>
    <h2 id="ctrl-notice"><%= "#{notice}" %></h2>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to exclude my <head> section of my control_panel template? I need to use the @title variable to set the title somewhere. Where should I do this?

Comment: yeah I'd exclude it... you don't technically need to put your `@title`-setting inside any tag... it'll still work just as floating ruby-tag at the top of your template... :sparkles: rails-magic! :sparkles: :)